# Where is the list of questions you have starred?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks

Okay, I'm losing my mind.

Where is the list of the questions you have starred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the new profile system, it’s not on your Profile page but rather on [your Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity), under [Favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites).

Comment: Thanks!  I thought all my marbles came loose.  It's not good design that they put it after tags and badges, and completely omitted it from the Summary page, but now that you've shown me where it is, I won't forget... until tomorrow.  ;-)